# Taxonomies on custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, children, multi-taxonomy-query

I have a custom post type with multiple custom taxonomies. I need those taxonomies to have a relationship as well. The trick is, I need a child to be able to have multiple parents. I understand that the current db structure for WordPress doesn't allow for this, but I was curious if anyone has dealt with this and had an elegant solution.

I'll update if I figure it out first.